# Error al realizar filtro por rango de fecha C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

si me pueden ayudar tengo un formulario con un DataGridViewer con dos detePicker y quiero ralizar un filtro de fecha, pero que pasa cuando trato de filtrar ejemplo desde el dia 1 al dia 2 me arroja tambien el dia 3, no esta siendo especisifico

```
private void FiltrarPorRangoDeFecha(DateTime fechaDesde, DateTime fechaHasta)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    string fechaDesdeStr = fechaDesde.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string fechaHastaStr = fechaHasta.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // Agregar 1 día al límite superior

    dv.RowFilter = $"[FechaFactura] >= #{fechaDesdeStr}# AND [FechaFactura] < #{fechaHastaStr}#";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

    if (dv.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se encontraron registros que coincidan con el rango de fechas.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! un ejemplo con datos es mucho mejor.. y no se que tendra que ver la etiqueta windows ;)

Comment: Che pero si yo en desde mando el valor 01/01/2023 y en hasta mando 02/01/2023 al añadirle un día extra a tu hasta, tu between quedará con desde 01/01/2023 hasta 03/01/2023, ¿O me equivoco?